# How to get a array of string like ["#{xxxx}","#{yyyy}"] from a string like "abc#{xxxx}def#{yyyy}ghi" using java?

Tags: java

How to get a array of string like *["#{xxxx}","#{yyyy}"]* from a string like *"abc#{xxxx}def#{yyyy}ghi"* using java?

I'm not good at English so I have to make great effort to express my question.
I want to take the uel expressions out, so I think there may be some methods existing to solve this situation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour], read [ask], and go through the [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    //remove first substring from input
    String formattedInput = input.substring(input.indexOf("#"), input.lastIndexOf("}") + 1);

    //make a regex that checks for string enclosed in } #{
    String regex = "(?<=[}])[A-Za-z]*(?=[#])";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(formattedInput);

    //remove the characters between } and #{
    if (m.find()) {
        formattedInput = formattedInput.replaceAll(regex, "");
    }


    System.out.println(formattedInput);

}
```

Input: **abc#{xxxx}def#{yyyy}**

Output: **#{xxxx}#{yyyy}**

I am not really sure as to what you are trying to ask because your question was not worded properly, but this code will remove any characters that are not enclosed in the #{} tag. You can then **split the resultant string into an array**. I hope this helps

Comment: thanks.
I'm not good at English so I have to make great effort to express my question.
I want to take the uel expressions out, so I think there may be some methods existing to solve this situation.